# How do I put data from one column into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a column of data:

```
Item
NaN
item_a
description_a
price_a
NaN
item_b
description_b
price_b
NaN
item_c
description_c
price_c
```

This is all in the same column `Item`. Everywhere there's a NaN in the column, I want to put the data below it in a separate column.

Like this:

```
Item1             Item2             Item3
item_a            item_b            item_c
description_a     description_b     description_c
price_a           price_b           price_c
```

Is there a way to transpose it only on the `NaN`'s? Or am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

A few boolean statements and a `unstack()` should do the trick.

```
df['item'] = np.where(df['Item'].str.contains('item',case=False),df['Item'],np.nan)
df['item'] = df['item'].ffill()

df1 = df.loc[df['item'].ne(df['Item'])].dropna()

df1['item_2'] = df1['item'].factorize()[0] + 1

df2 = df1.set_index([df1.groupby('item').cumcount(), 
              df1['item_2'],df1['item']])[['Item']].unstack([1,2]).droplevel(0,1)



print(df2)

item_2              1              2              3
item           item_a         item_b         item_c
0       description_a  description_b  description_c
1             price_a        price_b        price_c
```

Answer (score -1):

You should provide a better example and more details. Do you know the exact amount of NaNs in your row?

```
from typing import List
import pandas as pd


def split_row(value: str) -> List[str]:
    tmp = value.split("NaN")
    return tmp[1:]


def run():

    # List of new columns, has to match the length of split_row list
    item_list = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Item": [""""NaN
item_a
description_a
price_a
NaN
item_b
description_b
price_b
NaN
item_c
description_c
price_c"""]})

    print(df)
    print("-" * 70)

    df[item_list] = df["Item"].apply(split_row).to_list()
    df.drop("Item", axis=1)

    pd.set_option("max_columns", None)  # To print all columns
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

output:

```
                                                Item
0  "NaN\nitem_a\ndescription_a\nprice_a\nNaN\nite...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                Item  \
0  "NaN\nitem_a\ndescription_a\nprice_a\nNaN\nite...   

                                Item1                               Item2  \
0  \nitem_a\ndescription_a\nprice_a\n  \nitem_b\ndescription_b\nprice_b\n   

                              Item3  
0  \nitem_c\ndescription_c\nprice_c
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the best solution, but it works. The code below works only if every column start with a `NaN`, that implies, the first value of your "column" (I made it a list) is a `NaN`

```py
def traspose(l):
    b = []
    c = []
    for i in l:
       if i != i:
           if c == []:
               continue
           b += [c]
           c = []
           continue
       c += [i]
       if i == a[-1]:
           b += [c]
    return b

a = [
     float('NaN'), 'item_a', 'description_a', 'price_a',
    float('NaN'), 'item_b', 'description_b', 'price_b',
    float('NaN'), 'item_c', 'description_c', 'price_c'
    ]
print(traspose(a))
```

Output:

```py
[['item_a', 'description_a', 'price_a'],
['item_b', 'description_b', 'price_b'],
['item_c', 'description_c', 'price_c']]
```

Comment: Just some friendly advice, the Pandas API is extremely rich and has lot of inbuild functions one could use before resorting to vanilla python, secondly the base of the api is written in C, making it very fast when processing data, so when you resort to vanilla python you lose speed, and the flexibility of the api.